# How to resolve TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, nested

i'm trying to access specific json data and below is the code. im using python 2.7. however it come out with error **TypeError: string indices must be integers:**

```
http = win32com.client.Dispatch('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0')
http.open('POST', 'url', False, username, password)
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type"    , "text/json"             )
http.setRequestHeader("User-Agent"      , "Your User Agent String")
http.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding" , "gzip, deflate"         )
http.setRequestHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip, deflate"         )
global data
http.send(json)

global data
data = http.responseText
#data=data.split("{}{}") -try to make json data print nicely but failed.
print data['responses'][0]['status']
```

---

my json data is as below

```
{
    "responses": [
        {
            "tran_id": "1234",
            "UUID": "122262d7-85f8-4e53-af98-865627cb82cb",
            "status": "success",
            "messages": [],
            "result_params": {
                "record_count": "1"
            },
            "result_table": [
                {
                    "id": "101160766",
                    "rev": "13",
                    "hierarchy_id": "F80005AF46FF0000B5EA6FE06078159E80",
                    "is_current": "1"}}
```

,

Comment: your json is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong `JSON`, which is missing some brackets at the end.

```
"is_current": "1"}}
```

should change to

```
"is_current": "1"}]}]}
```

**[>>Demo<<](https://ideone.com/sZrC6p)**

Comment: the JSON is correct. it from some website. im the one who copy it wrongly. but the point is there. it come out with error when i try to read specific data from nested JSON data

Comment: But, it is working fine. You could refer my Demo link

Comment: i wonder is it because my real json data that i get is not in well indented as i shown above. above data i direct copy from json output that i get from postman apps. the info is the same. only the way data is printed is different. do you think it is the reason why it is not works with me?

Comment: i tried to do pretty print but also failed. but when i print type(data), it shown that im in unicode type

Answer (score 0):

a) Your "content-type" header field is incorrect. It should be application/json.

b) Your "content-encoding" header field is probably incorrect. It says you're sending *both* deflate- and gzip-encoded data.

Comment: do you have any suggestion for b) ? cause im not familiar with deflate and gzip-encoded data